# React not rendering what is being returned by a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "Tasks" function component that has a "tasks" state which is an array of tasks that is loaded from the backend using useEffect. The render method renders a list of the tasks in the state as "Task" components, among other things.

The issue I am having is that when I delete a task, the backend is updated, the tasks component updates its "tasks" state using data grabbed from the backend, and it should then re render with the newly updated tasks array, but it does not re render properly. The last element in the tasks state array is no longer visible, however it is not deleted from the backend, while the deleted task is deleted from the backend but is still visible. I have confirmed as best I can that the Task components being returned by the Tasks component are correct, and the state of Tasks is definitely correct.

Tasks Component:

```
import Task from './Task'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { getLoggedIn, getToken } from '../../context/loggedInState';
import { get } from "../../tools/request";
import AddTask from '../Tasking/AddTask';
import { useAddTask, useAddTaskUpdate } from '../../context/AddTaskContext'
import { FaAngleRight, FaAngleDoubleRight, FaCommentsDollar } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useToDoContext, useUpdateToDoContext } from '../../context/ToDoContext';



const Tasks = () => {
    const [reload, setReload] = useState(true);
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
    const loggedIn = getLoggedIn()
    const showAddTask = useAddTask();
    const toggleAddTask = useAddTaskUpdate();
    const toDoContext = useToDoContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch todos
        if (loggedIn === true && reload === true) {
            console.log("refreshing tasks");
            get("/api/task/getTasks")
                .then((resJson) => {
                    if (resJson.tasks !== undefined) {
                        console.log("setting task")
                        setTasks(resJson.tasks);
                        for (const task in tasks) {
                            console.log(`fetched tasks: ${task.title}`)
                        }
                        setReload(false);
                    }
                })
        } else {
            return (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            )
        }
    }, [reload])



    const handleHover = () => {
        setHover(!hover)
    }

    var test = `
        
        <div>
            <div name='addTaskCtn' className=${showAddTask ? 'invisible add-task-container' : 'visible add-task-container'}
                onMouseEnter=${handleHover}
                onMouseLeave=${handleHover}>
                <FaAngleRight name='angleRight' className=${hover ? 'invisible add-task-angle' : 'add-task-angle'} />
                <FaAngleDoubleRight name='angleRightDouble' className=${hover ? 'add-task-angle hover' : 'invisible add-task-angle'} />
                <button name='addTask' onClick=${toggleAddTask}
                    className=${hover ? 'add-task-btn hover' : 'add-task-btn'}
                >Add Task</button>
            </div>
            <div name='AddTaskForm' className=${showAddTask ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}>
                <AddTask setReload=${setReload} />
            </div>
            <div name='taskList' className='task-list'>
                ${tasks.map((task, index) => {
                    if (toDoContext.currentBucket == "" || task.buckets.includes(toDoContext.currentBucket)) {
                        return task.title
                    }
                })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    `
    console.log(`Test: ${test}`)
    return (
        <div>
            <div name='addTaskCtn' className={showAddTask ? 'invisible add-task-container' : 'visible add-task-container'}
                onMouseEnter={handleHover}
                onMouseLeave={handleHover}>
                <FaAngleRight name='angleRight' className={hover ? 'invisible add-task-angle' : 'add-task-angle'} />
                <FaAngleDoubleRight name='angleRightDouble' className={hover ? 'add-task-angle hover' : 'invisible add-task-angle'} />
                <button name='addTask' onClick={toggleAddTask}
                    className={hover ? 'add-task-btn hover' : 'add-task-btn'}
                >Add Task</button>
            </div>
            <div name='AddTaskForm' className={showAddTask ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}>
                <AddTask setReload={setReload} />
            </div>
            <div name='taskList' className='task-list'>
                {tasks.map((task, index) => {
                    if (toDoContext.currentBucket == "" || task.buckets.includes(toDoContext.currentBucket)) {
                        return <Task key={index} task={task} setReload={setReload} />
                    }
                })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tasks;
```

Task Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FaSun, FaTimes, FaEdit, FaCalendar } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { post } from "../../tools/request";
import { getToken } from '../../context/loggedInState';
import { useToDoContext, useUpdateToDoContext } from '../../context/ToDoContext';

const Schedule = ({}) => {
    return (
        <div className='test'>test</div>
    )
}

const Task = ({ task, setReload }) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(task.title)
    const [buckets, setBuckets] = useState(task.buckets)
    const [body, setBody] = useState(task.body)
    const [id, setId] = useState(task._id);
    const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(task.reminder)
    const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState(task.dueDate)
    const [calendar, setCalendar] = useState(false);
    const toDoContext = useToDoContext();
    const updateToDoContext = useUpdateToDoContext();

    function editTask() {
        post("/api/task/editTask", {
            "id": id,
            title,
            body
        })
            .then((resJson) => {
                if (resJson.error === true) {
                    console.log("Error submiting new task");
                } else {
                    updateToDoContext({...toDoContext, reloadBuckets: true})
                    setReload(true);
                }
            })
    }

    function deleteTask() {
        post("/api/task/deleteTask", { "id": id, })
            .then((resJson) => {
                if (resJson.error === true) {
                    console.log("Error submiting new task");
                }
                console.log("deleting and reloading")
                setReload(true);
            })
    }

    function onBucket(e) {
        setBuckets(e.target.value)
    }
    function onTitle(e) {
        setTitle(e.target.value)
    }

    function onBody(e) {
        setBody(e.target.value);
    }

    function onReminder(e) {
        setReminder(e.target.value);
    }

    function moveTomorrow() {
        setDueDate(dueDate + 1);
    }
    function parseBody() {
        let track = false;
        var newBody = '';
        for (const char in body) {
            if (body[char] == "#") {
                track = true;
                continue
            }
            if (body[char] == " " && track == true) {
                track = false;
                continue
            }
            if (!track) {
                newBody = newBody.concat(body[char]);
            }
        }
        return newBody;
    }

    function toggleCalendar(e) {
        console.log("what happened")
        setCalendar(!calendar);
    }

    return (
        <div className='task-item' >
            <div className='task-header'>
                <h3 className='task-element task-title'>{title}</h3>
                <div className='fade-out'></div>
                <span className='task-icons'>
                    <FaSun className='task-icon' onClick={moveTomorrow} />
                    {/* Placeholder for "Move to tomorrow" icon */}
                    <FaEdit className='task-edit task-icon' onClick={editTask} />
                    {/* Edit Task */}
                    <FaTimes className='task-delete task-icon' onClick={deleteTask} />
                    {/* Delete */}
                    <FaCalendar className='task-delete task-icon' onClick={toggleCalendar}/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className='task-body'>
                <p className='task-element'>{parseBody()}</p>
                {buckets.map((bucket, index) => (
                        <span className='task-bucket task-element'key={index}>#{bucket}</span>
                    ))}
            </div>
            <span>   
                {dueDate}
            </span>


            {calendar ? <Schedule/> : null}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Task


/*
Notes:
This will be the area where I add features to the a given task's template.
This will edit the format of all Tasks that will be mapped in Tasks.jsx file.a

*/
```

This is an example of before I try and delete anything. All tasks are rendered properly.
[Before Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvbhQ.png)

This is after I delete the task titled "Task to be deleted":
[After Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzTW6.png)

Here you can see that in fact the task that was deleted is still being showed, while the last task was removed. The "Tasks" component tasks state is being showed on the right, it does not contain the deleted task, and does contain the last task that is no longer being showed.

I have printed in the console what should be returned by the "Tasks" component, it also shows the correct tasks. It is like react is not rendering what is being returned by the "Tasks" component. I am not sure what is causing this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend looked at this and gave me an answer, I found a second one as well.

React uses the keys of the elements in a list to keep track of which elements have been changed, updated, or deleted. The components were not being recreated as I thought they were on each render. Instead react was seeing that there is one less key, so the task with the key that was missing (the last task) was not being displayed. Each key, while unique, was not associated with a specific task. It was just the index of the task in the array. One solution provided by my friend was to add a useEffect method to my Task component to have each task update when the task prop being passed in changes like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTitle(task.title);
        setBuckets(task.buckets);
        setBody(task.body);
        setId(task._id);
    }, [task])
```

Another solution is to set the key of each task to the id of the task. This way each task is provided with a key that can identify it directly, not by index. A key at any index that changes will then be updated. However if the contents of a task change, a task will not be updated because the key will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should `setReload` is false before call api in `deleteTask`. It make sure reload will change after fetch API success and useEffect will be called.

```
function deleteTask() {
  setReload(false);
  post("/api/task/deleteTask", { id: id }).then((resJson) => {
    if (resJson.error === true) {
      console.log("Error submiting new task");
    }
    console.log("deleting and reloading");
    setReload(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: useEffect is being called. reload is set to false every time useEffect runs so something can always set it to true again to reload from the backend.